emulate lighting from solid mode in high-res render in Blender 4.2
is there a way to emulate the lighting from solid mode for a proper high-res rendering? I use Blender (4.2.0) to render SfM's for research and I like how surface morphology displays in solid mode, but I would like to create high-res renders for publication.
Using the View/Viewport Render Image is already quite nice but I would like to tweak the lights and shadows a bit more using some nodes. So the question is whether it's possible to emulate the general light similar to solid mode and modify it further with spot lights and nodes such as the "Glossy BSDF" etc.
Thx and cheers!

If there are no special things to take into account which you forgot mentioning, then why not just render the viewport in Solid shading mode?
Let's say I have Suzanne here in the viewport in Solid shading:

If I then go to View > Viewport Render Image the camera view gets rendered with the resolution which is set in the Output Properties, in my case 1920×1080 pixels.

And the render result:

Of course you probably do not want the overlays for publication, so disable them by clicking on the Overlays button:

And now the viewport render is "clean":

The good thing is also, you can either render from the camera view or from any other arbitrary viewing angle which you are currently looking at in the viewport without the need of a camera:

If you do not want to go through the menu, you can right-click on the menu entry and assign a shortcut to it (or add it to the Quick Favorites menu).
